# ¿Cómo escribir un número máximo de dígitos en sprintf?

Tags: string, c

Si tengo un array en el que quiero componer una cadena y quiero asegurarme de no tener desbordamientos cuando escribo cadenas lo puedo hacer tal que así :

```
void componer( char compuesto[100], const char* cadena1, const char* cadena2 )
{
  sprintf( compuesto, "%.40s--%.40s", cadena1, cadena2 );
}
```

De esa forma me aseguro de no desbordar nunca el array `compuesto` independientemente de la longitud de las cadenas `cadena1` y `cadena2` porque `%.40s` significa escribir una cadena pero como mucho 40 caracteres.

Pero para enteros el ancho(width) y la precisión en el formato de `printf` y funciones similares significa el número mínimo de caracteres a imprimir, pero se pueden imprimir más.

El problema es que esta función :

```
void componeInt( char compuesto[14], int a, int b)
{
  sprintf( compuesto, "%d/%d", a, b );
}
```

va a funcionar bien en arquitecturas en que int sea de 16 bits; porque como múcho un int tiene 5 cifras decimales, 6 con el signo negativo. Y con 14 caracteres hay siempre espacio para almacenar esa cadena.

Pero en arquitecturas de 32 bits voy a tener un desbordamiento del array.

¿Hay algún parámetro de formato de sprintf para restringir el número máximo de caracteres a imprimir en un entero? ¿Si no lo hay, cómo hacerlo? Me da igual si del número parcialmente escrito se escriben las cifras más significativas o las menos significativas.

Comment: si entiendo bien su pregunta igual puede usar -> http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/ Saludos

Comment: Sí, eso me va perfecto. Y mi compilador de C lo acepta. Ponlo como respuesta.

Comment: es para c99 pero creo que para MSVC no se si tendra problemas

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lo primero es lo primero.

En un código C moderno no debería estar bien visto usar los tipos clásicos `int`, `short`, etc, ya que su rango de valores depende de la máquina en la que estemos trabajando. En su lugar sería más conveniente usar los tipos dados por la librería `stdint.h`. Los tipos definidos en esta librería presentan la ventaja de que su rango de valores es fijo para cualquier máquina, lo cual evita sorpresas desagradables al diseñar aplicaciones a compilar para múltiples dispositivos.

Dicho esto una primera aproximación podría hacerse usando tipos con rango fijo:

```
void componeInt( char compuesto[14], int16_t a, int16_t b)
```

O dejar la firma con los tipos clásicos y hacer un cast dentro de la función, aunque en este caso puede que acabemos truncando el valor y perdiendo dígitos:

```
void componeInt( char compuesto[14], int a, int b)
{
  sprintf( compuesto, "%d/%d", (int16_t )a, (int16_t )b );
}
```

Una tercera opción pasa por no usar `sprintf`, función todo sea dicho de paso, catalogada como insegura porque no es capaz de controlar el desbordamiento de buffer. En su lugar es más seguro usar `snprintf`. Esta función recibe, además de un buffer donde almacenar la salida, el tamaño máximo de almacenamiento. Esto impide escribir fuera del buffer a costa de sacrificar el final de la cadena:

```
void componeInt( char compuesto[14], int a, int b)
{
  snprintf( compuesto, 14, "%d/%d", a, b );
}
```

Lo malo que tiene esta última solución es que podemos perder el último `int` completamente. Si es un requisito mostrar los dos valores, aunque sea parcialmente, la mejor solución pasa por conjugar las soluciones que hemos visto en una sola. Bueno, realmente una o dos, dependiendo de los requisitos:

**Truncando los valores dentro de la función**

```
void componeInt( char compuesto[14], int a, int b)
{
  snprintf( compuesto, 14, "%d/%d", (int16_t )a, (int16_t )b );
}
```

**Limitando el tamaño de las variables directamente en la firma**

```
void componeInt( char compuesto[14], int16_t a, int16_t b)
{
  snprintf( compuesto, 14, "%d/%d", a, b );
}
```

Lo bueno que tienen estas dos soluciones es que hacen uso de una función segura `snprintf` en vez de una insegura, `sprintf`. Quizás entre estas dos posibles soluciones la más elegante sea la segunda, ya que al que vaya a hacer uso de la función le queda claro directamente en la firma que la función únicamente va a trabajar con valores de 16 bits.

**EDITO:**

Si se usan los tipos definidos en `stdin.h` y no queremos llevarnos sorpresas al imprimir éstas variables tenemos que usar las macros declaradas en `inttypes.h`. Estas macros garantizan que el valor se imprima de acuerdo a su rango concreto.

Bien es cierto que estas macros pueden complicar la lectura del código, pero es sólo un poco y en seguida se acostumbra uno a la nueva sintaxis:

```
void componeInt( char compuesto[14], int16_t a, int16_t b)
{
  snprintf( compuesto, 14, "%" PRId16 "/%" PRId16, a, b );
}
```

Comment: Esto que comentas: __En un código C moderno no debería estar bien visto usar los tipos clásicos int, short, etc, ya que su rango de valores depende de la máquina en la que estemos trabajando.__ es un poco radical, si bien es cierto que hay operaciones (sobre todo operaciones a nivel de bits) en las que conviene trabajar sabiendo el ancho en bits exacto, la mayoría de operaciones se pueden y de hecho se deben hacer (por compatibilidad con las librerías standard) o por velocidad (alineación en memória a un multiplo del word del procesador) sobre tipos enteros primitivos.

Comment: Utilizar tipos susceptibles de tener un rango variable puede tener implicaciones bastante serias si el rango puede cambiar a menos. ¿Comentario radical? Puede ser o puede que no, depende del ámbito final del proyecto y del uso de la variable. En lo referente al lenguaje moderno... el tema de los tipados fijos viene si mal no recuerdo del estándar C99 por lo que moderno moderno no lo veo. Se puede usar o no... Lo que sucede es que mucha gente desconoce estas características del estándar.

Comment: Normalmente basta con escoger el  tipo correcto ya que [los rangos mínimos están garantizados](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6155838/1606345), es de cajón que si vamos a guardar un día de la semana no necesitamos un `long long` ni vamos a usar un `short` para almacenar un índice del censo Chino, normalmente (casi siempre) sabemos cual va a ser el valor máximo. En mi opinión los tipos de ancho fijo están para lo que están, es mucho más seguro (portable) usar `uint32_t x = flag & 0xFFFF;` que `unsigned x = flag & 0xFFFF;`, pero su uso no es extrapolable a todos los usos ni mucho menos.

Comment: De todos modos e independientemente de si usar tipos de ancho fijo o tipos primitivos, la solución al problema usando un cast es muy buena, aunque no está de más que la función devuelva el retorno de `snprintf` en lugar de `void`.

Comment: Está claro que en programación no hay nada que pueda generalizarse para todos los casos posibles. En los proyectos en los que yo trabajo veo más fiable usar tipos de rango fijo para evitar errores al cambiar de plataforma... imagínate dos aplicaciones en distintas arquitecturas conectadas por sockets... si los rangos no coinciden el resultado puede ser decepcionante por decirlo suavemente... y tener que usar el tipo con el rango mínimo garantizado puede no ser lo más recomendable de cara a reutilizar código en ambas aplicaciones.

Comment: Mi opinión personal es que estos tipos se usan muy poco sobretodo porque se suele desconocer su mera existencia. En cuanto a lo de retornar `void`, sí que sería una posible mejora, pero mi idea era centrarme en el uso de los tipos y lo del return, aunque una buena práctica, no formaba parte de la idea que quería exponer.

Comment: Si, lo del `void` era un consejo para Jose Antonio.

Comment: `... imagínate dos aplicaciones en distintas arquitecturas conectadas por sockets...` de hecho lo sufro a diario, precisamente por eso nunca me comunico con otra máquina usando un tipo diferente a `char` (lo que en inglish llaman chunk of bytes), en esas aguas turbulentas hay que tener en cuenta el tamaño en bytes, el orden (endianness), y lo más peliagudo: cliente y servidor deben saber de antemano el tamaño del paquete en bytes (ya que no está garantizado que el paquete se mande en un solo `send`). Prefiero no hacer versiones especializadas para cada envío y usar `char` siempre.

Answer (score 4):

Usted puede tratar de usar [int snprintf ( char * s, size_t n, const char * format, ... );](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/) en una parte de la documentacion pone algo asi:

> Si la cadena resultante es mas largo que n-1 caracteres, los
>   caracteres restantes se descartan y no se almacenan, pero contadas por
>   el valor devuelto por la función.

**n** Parametro:

> Maximum number of bytes to be used in the buffer.  The generated
>   string has a length of at most n-1, leaving space for the additional
>   terminating null character. size_t is an unsigned integral type.

El numero maximo de `bytes` que se utiliza en la memoria intermedia.

La cadena generada tiene una longitud de como `maximo n-1`, dejando espacio para la terminación carácter nulo adicional.
size_t es un tipo entero sin signo.

**Notas:** Snprinf es parte del estandar C99.